# Pandas "Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects" while comparing identically dataframes.

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, compare

I'm trying to compare two dataframes in Python. 
Data frames have exactly same labels, but data inside is mixed, so I need to sort it up by one key column. 
Problem appears after "sort_values" function is used.

This code is working, but I'm getting FALSE's because data is ordered in diffrent way:

```
l1 = l1.reindex(sorted(change.columns), axis=1)
l2 = l2.reindex(sorted(change.columns), axis=1)
# l1.sort_values("PPID", inplace=True, axis=0, ascending=True)
# l2.sort_values("PPID", inplace=True, axis=0, ascending=True)
print(l1 == l2)
```

This code should work in my opinion, data is by sorted "PPID", labels still looks the same, but I'm getting error:

```
l1 = l1.reindex(sorted(change.columns), axis=1)
l2 = l2.reindex(sorted(change.columns), axis=1)
l1.sort_values("PPID", inplace=True, axis=0, ascending=True)
l2.sort_values("PPID", inplace=True, axis=0, ascending=True)
print(l1 == l2)
```

Error message:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

What is causing this error? Is there any different way to sort by column, or to compare two dataframes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I though that dataframes are identically labeled, but it was not true. 
.sort_values sorted even row indexes, so one dataframe had 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc. and the other had 6,3,2,4,5,1...After I changed indexes I was able to compare df's.